# Using Lua in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, lua, luacode

I am currently exploring ways to generate TikZ code using LuaTeX.
Using the `luacode*` environment seems to be smooth sailing. But sometimes it seems to make more sense to just inject small fragments using Lua into the TikZ environment instead of using hordes of `tex.sprint()` statements.
This seems like a mine field. Given the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\luadirect{tex.print("\string\\draw (0,0) to (1,1);")}  % #1 works
\luaexec{tex.print("\\draw (0,0) to (1,1);")}           % #2 works
\draw (0,0) to (\luaexec{tex.sprint("1,1")});           % #3 does not work
\draw (0,0) to (\luadirect{tex.sprint("1,1")});         % #4 works
\draw (0,0) to \luaexec{tex.sprint("(1,1)")};           % #5 doesn't work
\draw (0,0) to \luadirect{tex.sprint("(1,1)")};         % #6 doesn't work
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why do #1, #2 and #4 work and #3, #5 and #6 don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors are not directly related to Lua, it is simply a matter of whether tikz is allowing macros or non expandable commands at certain points, you see the same errors for the same reasons with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\zz{\draw (0,0) to (1,1);}\zz           % #1 works
\def\zz{\draw (0,0) to (1,1);}\zz           % #2 works
%\draw (0,0) to (\def\zz{1,1}\zz);           % #3 does not work
\def\zz{1,1}\draw (0,0) to (\zz);           % #4 works
%\draw (0,0) to \def\zz{(1,1)}\zz;           % #5 doesn't work
%\def\zz{(1,1)}\draw (0,0) to \zz;           % #6 doesn't work
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I find it is often easier to use `\directlua` (which is expandable) rather than the luacode wrapper which mostly are not expandable as they include catcode assignments to make characters "safe"

Comment: I was hoping you would answer the question "Using LUA in tikzpicture" with "`\tikz{\node{LUA};}`", but no.... ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat `\begin{picture}\directlua{...}` ?

Comment: The question is "Using LUA in **tikz**picture", so no...

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat oh you mean like "draw aircraft with tikz" ?

Comment: Indeed, this one is a great contribution to fight climate change: dysfunctional planes. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat “Lua” is not an acronym.

Comment: @HenriMenke Of course it is, it is a hybrid between Lufthansa and United Airlines, which is why David brought up the plane. ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You can make #6 work relatively easily. ``\let\tikz@@@to@collect\tikz@@to@collect
\def\tikz@@to@collect{\expandafter\tikz@@@to@collect\romannumeral-`0}
``